# How to setup notification sound and "orange blinking tab"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a notification to my simple php/js chat:

First, I'm trying to compare my log.html (which containing the messages):

my original post.php (    //jQuery request. It posts the client's input and data being sent to the post.php file each time the user submits the form and sends a new message.) The. post.php is saving the messages into log.html file.

```
 <?php
 session_start();

 if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $text_message = "<div class='msgln'><span class='chat-time'>".date("F j, g:i A")."</span> <b class='user-name'>".$_SESSION['name']."</b> ".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."<br></div>";

    file_put_contents("log.html", $text_message, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
?>
```

my edited post.php (trying to set up a function, which is checking the "new" message - comparing with old ones).

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    $text = $_POST['text'];     
 
    $text_message = "<div class='msgln'><span class='chat-time'>".date("F j, g:i A")."</span> <b class='user-name'>".$_SESSION['name']."</b> ".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."<br></div>";

    // Check if content is different

    function text_check(){
        $ah = fopen("log.html", 'rb');
        $aha = preg_match(fread($ah, 8192), $text_message);
        $result = true;

        while(!feof($ah)) {
            if( $aha === false){
                $result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        fclose($ah);
        return $result;    
    }

file_put_contents("log.html", $text_message, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);    
}
?>
```

If post.php function "text_check()" return true in my index.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkUpdate()
{
    $.post("post.php", function(text_check){
        if (text_check.toString()=="true") {
            playSound();
        }
    });
}

function playSound()
{
    var audio = new Audio('my_audio');
    audio.play();
}
```

Is it a OK conception?

And how can I make an "orang-red blinking" notification, when browser is minimized?

I read something about title - have to change it. Will it work, if I change it every second with JS?

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: While its perfectly legal to put functions randomly in the middle of other code, it does not contribute to the easy understanding of whats going on in a script. Can I suggest you code your functions either at the top or the bottom of your script files, not wherever you think them up

Comment: @RiggsFolly i posted only code snippets. The point is, to make a notification, when new message arrived. As i don't have database (only basic chat - made by php/JS), i thought, i should check messages in my log.html (where messages are saved). My original post.php file is saving the messages. If message exists in my log.html file, the function would return a false value (i don't now, if it's working). With ajax, i'm trying to make a sound notification (if value is true = there is a new message, because message is not exists in file).